# How should I implement if varA not selected display not selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I have a simple product page with a few sizes and an add to cart button. I want to use jquery to `$("").toggle();` a message saying "choose a size" if a size isn't selected `onClick` of the Add to Cart button.

Here is my code:

ryan.js

```
function ryanClicked(id, b, c){
  b = b || null;
  c = c || null;
document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor = "black";
document.getElementById(b).style.borderColor = "#e0e0e0";
document.getElementById(c).style.borderColor = "#e0e0e0";
}
```

html.html

```
<div class="pp">
<div id ="sizeButton1"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked('sizeButton1','sizeButton2','sizeButton3')">      S </div>
<div id ="sizeButton2"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked('sizeButton2','sizeButton1','sizeButton3')">      M </div>
<div id ="sizeButton3"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked('sizeButton3','sizeButton1','sizeButton2')">      L </div>
</div>          <br>
//I want to prevent the onClick from happening if size is not selected
<p class="ryanAddButton" onclick="simpleCart.add('quantity=1','name=Black Gold','price=58','image=images/thumbs/blackGold.jpg');return false;" >Add to Cart</p>

<p class ="hiddenTilClicked"> You must select a size! </p>
```

I want the `onclick` to be called when a size is selected and I want a jquery toggle to be called if a size is not selected.

*How can I do this?* I can just use js if statement but I don't know how to use JS to display html.

edit: can i pass in a function to be called in js? is that a callback?  the simplecart.add() will have different parameters for each item

Comment: Ryan, let me know if none of the answers worked so I can help

Comment: they helped great! I just am thinking about how I am going to write this so that I can remove repeating code. I originally was going to make a product page for each product I'm selling then just copy and paste different images but it seems to be a bit more tricky than that.

Comment: `so that I can remove repeating code. ` You should be able to modularize  across different pages. It does not have to be tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to set a style and width on your border.
2. Use a variable to track if a style was selected or not.
3. `b = b || null` isnt needed because you always pass in a parameter

```js
var sizeSelected = false;

function ryanClicked(id, b, c) {
  sizeSelected = true;
  document.getElementById(id).style.border = "1px solid black";
  document.getElementById(b).style.border = "1px solid #e0e0e0";
  document.getElementById(c).style.border = "1px solid #e0e0e0";
}

function addClicked() {
  if (sizeSelected) {
    document.getElementById('hiddenTilClicked').style.display = 'none';
    simpleCart.add('quantity=1', 'name=Black Gold', 'price=58', 'image=images/thumbs/blackGold.jpg');

  } else {
    document.getElementById('hiddenTilClicked').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.hiddenTilClicked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pp">
  <div id="sizeButton1" class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked('sizeButton1','sizeButton2','sizeButton3')">S</div>
  <div id="sizeButton2" class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked('sizeButton2','sizeButton1','sizeButton3')">M</div>
  <div id="sizeButton3" class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked('sizeButton3','sizeButton1','sizeButton2')">L</div>
</div>
<br>
<p class="ryanAddButton" onclick="addClicked();">Add to Cart</p>

<p id="hiddenTilClicked" class="hiddenTilClicked">You must select a size!</p>
```

Comment: Isn't `b = b || null;` the same with a simple `b;`, the line should be removed case it has no value.

Comment: Oh, I see that everybody did it :)

Comment: @curieux, I must be only half-awake :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a flag that tells if a button has been clicked or not. And instead of directly calling the add function of the simpleCart you can make a new function for the click and wrap your product addition to the cart happen only when a button has been clicked.

You also need to set the hidden element hidden by style and toggle the style to visible only when the customer tries to add a product to the cart without selecting a size.

HTML:

```
<div class="pp">
<div id ="sizeButton1"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(this.id)">      S </div>
<div id ="sizeButton2"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(this.id)">      M </div>
<div id ="sizeButton3"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(this.id)">      L </div>
</div>          <br>
//I want to prevent the onClick from happening if size is not selected
<p class="ryanAddButton" onclick="simpleCart.add('quantity=1','name=Black Gold','price=58','image=images/thumbs/blackGold.jpg');return false;" >Add to Cart</p>

<p id="hiddenTilClicked" style={ visibility: none }> You must select a size! </p>
```

JS:

```
var sizeSelected = false;

function ryanClicked(id){
    // set the flag that some size has been selected
    sizeSelected = true;

    // hide the warning since a size was selected
    $('#hiddenTilClicked').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    // add the border colors
    $('.sizeButton').each(function(i, element) {
        if(element.id == id) {
            element.style.borderColor = "black";
        } else {
            element.style.borderColor = "#e0e0e0";
        }
    });
}

function addToCart() {
    // add to cart only when a size was selected
    if(sizeSelected) {
        simpleCart.add('quantity=1','name=Black Gold','price=58','image=images/thumbs/blackGold.jpg')
    } else {
        $('#hiddenTilClicked').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle where you can test it: http://jsfiddle.net/sqkosy0b/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag and put this `simpleCart.add('quantity=1','name=Black Gold','price=58','image=images/thumbs/blackGold.jpg');return false;"` inside JS:

HTML:

```
<p class="ryanAddButton" onclick="checkIfSel()" >Add to Cart</p>
```

JS:

```
var flag=0;
function ryanClicked(id, b, c){
  b = b || null;
  c = c || null;
document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor = "black";
document.getElementById(b).style.borderColor = "#e0e0e0";
document.getElementById(c).style.borderColor = "#e0e0e0";
flag=1;
}

function checkIfSel(){
 if(flag==1){
  simpleCart.add('quantity=1','name=Black Gold','price=58','image=images/thumbs/blackGold.jpg');
  $('.hiddenTilClicked').hide();
 }
 else{
  $('.hiddenTilClicked').show(); //OR document.getElementsByClassName('hiddenTilClicked')[0].style.display="block";
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set a variable in ryanclicked that will check if a button has been clicked:

add this line to ryan clicked:

```
sizeselect = false;
function ryanClicked(id, b, c) {
  sizeselect = true;
 }
```

You can associate a function with the onclick button like this:

`<p class="ryanAddButton" onclick="checkforclick()" >Add to Cart</p>`

And you can define your function like this:

```
function checkforclick()
{
 if(sizeselect)
 {
   simpleCart.add('quantity=1', 'name=Black Gold', 'price=58', 'image=images/thumbs/blackGold.jpg');
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementsByClassName('hiddenTilClicked')[0].style.display = 'block';
 }
}
```